# No Wifi Adapter found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

i'm using Ubuntu desktop installed on lenovo laptop with realtek wireless card and recently i can't access the internet and instead of the wifi signal i got <*> symbol and in the wifi section i got the `no wifi adapter found` after a lot of googling and youtube tutorials, all the solutions i've found need the device to be connected to the internet and i'v tried

- Wifi
- Ethernet
- usb tethering
- blutooth tethering

and none of them work, so how can i install the wifi adapter offline

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: There are many different Lenovo laptop models and many different Realtek wireless cards; we still don't know which you have.